# Expressjs redirects user to a wrong route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have following registration page

```
form(method='post', action='users/register')
    .form-group
        label Name
        input.form-control(name='name', type='text',placeholder='Enter Name')
    .form-group
        label Email
        input.form-control(name='email', type='email',placeholder='Enter Email')
    .form-group
        label Username
        input.form-control(name='username', type='text',placeholder='Username')
    .form-group
        label Password
        input.form-control(name='password', type='password',placeholder='Enter Password')
    .form-group
        label Confirm Password
        input.form-control(name='password2', type='password',placeholder='Confirm Password')
    input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit',value='Register')
```

and on the server side, in users.js route, I have following code

```
router.post('/register', function (req, res, next) {
    // code here
});
```

Now when I press `Register` button, the it redirects user to `users/users/register` route. **Why and how can I solve this?**

I am using `express 4.13.1`

Comment: probably be causes it's relative? Can you post where you register your router? Is the registration form at /users?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add / in the beginning of the form action else the action would be relative to the current url

`form(method='post', action='users/register')`

Or if you want to do it correctly

`form(method='post', action='register')`

this way the client is less sensitive for changes, for example if you would like to change users to accounts.